# Laravel: ErrorException (E_ERROR) Trying to get property of non-object (View:..../show.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, view, model, controller

Please help... i cannot see my mistake and i'm a newbie:

OrdersController.php:

```
public function show(Order $order)

    {
        return view('/orders.show', compact('order'));
    }
```

Order.php:

```
public function TypesOfTest()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TypesOfTest::class);
    }
```

show.blade.php:

```
    <div class="col-12">
      <p>Order for: {{ $order->patient->name . ' ' . $order->patient->fname}} </p>
      <p>Test type: {{ $order->TypesOfTest->nameOfTest }}</p>
    </div>

({ $order->TypesOfTest->nameOfTest }}  <-- is the problem
```

[DB: orders table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G48Lg.png)

[DB: types_of_tests table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fho2G.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a relationship, laravel permits you to define the keys involved into it. If you do not do it, for the foreign key it just adds the suffix `_id` to the name of the table.

In your case (not defining the foreign_key) it creates the error. Change your `belongsTo` relationship to this:

```
public function TypesOfTest()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TypesOfTest::class, 'typesOfTest_id');
}
```

Comment: Working !!
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship in model like:

**Order.php:**

```
public function TypesOfTest()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TypesOfTest::class, 'typesOfTest_id');
    }
```

**TypesOfTest.php**

```
public function order()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
```